# One-dimensional harmonic move - input parameter conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, velocity

I have one-dimensional harmonic move, but velocity is defined as function of distance from the beginning

V(x) = (**V***max* + **V***min*)/2 + (**V***max* - **V***min*)/2 * cos((2 * PI / **K** ) * x )

Where **V***max* > **V***min*, **V***min* > 0, and **K** > 0 are input constants. So my velocity starts at **V***max* and is oscillating between **V***max* and **V***min* with distance period **K** *[meter]*.

I want to know how this system evolve in time, resp. conversion of this system that depends on distance, to other that depends on time, so i am looking for:

- function for current velocity at time: $V*2*(t)$
- function for distance from beginning based on time: $D*2*(t)$

Comment: to obtain x(t) you have to solve this differential equation $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=v\left( x\right) $

Answer (score 0):

with:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=v (x)=a+b\,\cos(c\,x(t))$$

the solution of this differential equation with the initial condition $~x(0)=0$ is:

$$x(t)=\frac{2}{c}\,\arctan \left( {\frac {\tan \left( \frac 12\,t\,c\sqrt {{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}
 \right) \sqrt {{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}}{a-b}} \right) 
$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$v(t)=v(x\mapsto x(t))$$